# Can clusters overlap in hierarchical clustering?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

[Clustering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb20a.png)Can clusters overlap in hierarchical agglomerative clustering. I implemented a distance matrix in R and plotted the clusters but the result show that the clusters overlap one over the other.

```
library(rioja)

View(dissimilarity)

dissimilarity=as.dist(dissimilarity)

#diss=dist(dissimilarity,method='canberra')
clust1=chclust(dissimilarity,method = "coniss")     #To plot the dendogram using coniss method
#clust=chclust(dissimilarity,method = "conslink")    #To plot the dendogram using conslink method
plot(clust1,hang=-1)

#creating the hclust object to implement hierarchial clustering

hc = hclust(dissimilarity, method = 'ward.D')
y_hc = cutree(hc,6)
dissimilarity=as.matrix(dissimilarity)    #To convert diss into a data matrix  
# Visualising the clusters
library(cluster)
clusplot(dissimilarity,
         y_hc,
         lines = 0,
         shade = FALSE,
         color = TRUE,
         labels= 1,
         plotchar = FALSE,
         span = TRUE,
         main = paste('Clusters'),
         )
```

Comment: Which distance did you use? There shouldn't be overlaps in hierarchical clustering.

Comment: Please load up that plot to the question so we understand what you mean by overlap and give more detail on how you used which functions for clustering.

Comment: This is the code I have used and it is given to me that dissimilarity is already a dissimilarity matrix. it is also given the distances are non euclidean. @Bernhard

Comment: I have been given a dissimilarity matrix and its mentioned that it is non euclidean. Nothing else is specified. @CarlesMitjans

Comment: The image has been added as a link in the question @Bernhard

Comment: So if you reduce the unspecified number of dimensions to 2 using principal components then there is considerable overlapping in a plot of only the 2 first components. That does not mean, there is overlapping in n dimensions, whatever n may be.

Comment: So basically my clustering code is correct , right ? I can upload the data as well if you like ? @Bernhard

Comment: Even after using diss=TRUE , the clusters do overlap. The clusters are surely looking better but still overlapping. @Bernhard

Comment: Any chance of getting more information on how many dimensions there are in the original data?

Comment: http://owncloud.nathalievilla.org/index.php/s/MOUCeNrxkLsZ0SD This is the dataset . @Bernhard

Answer (score 2):

The impression of overlapping clusters may be based upon a 2D-plot of possible multidimensional data or upon false use of the function syntax. The function `clusplot` in package `cluster` uses `prcomp` or `cmdscale` depending on the argument `diss` being false or true for dimensionality reduction.

According to `help(clusplot)`, `diss` tells the function, whether a dissimilarity matrix or a matrix of observations is given to the function. I your case, a dissimilarity matrix is given to the function without setting `diss =  TRUE`. This is probably a wrong use of the plotting function.

Answer (score 0):

in hierarchical agglomerative clustering, clusters should not overlap.
Hierarchical clustering typically results in a tree-like structure called a dendrogram, where each level represents a different level of similarity or distance. The clusters formed in hierarchical clustering are mutually exclusive, meaning that each data point belongs to only one cluster at any given level of the hierarchy.
However, it is possible that the visual representation of clusters in the dendrogram or a scatter plot may give the impression of overlap if the data points are very close to each other.

In the code you provided, you are using the clusplot function from the "cluster" package to visualize the clusters. The clusplot function generates a scatter plot where the points represent the data and are assigned colors based on their clusters. It's important to note that in this type of plot, if the points are very close together in the space, they may visually overlap, but it doesn't necessarily imply that the clusters themselves are overlapping.

To assess if the clusters are truly overlapping, it is recommended to examine the structure of the dendrogram and the numerical results of the clustering, such as the sizes and composition of the clusters. It is also helpful to check if data points assigned to the same cluster have similarities to each other and significant differences with points from other clusters.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT output, not human output.